# Google+ embedding post 403 - recognize post from communities via api

Tags: google-plus, embedding

I have a list of google plus activities in a DB that i want to embed in a page.

In the official guide ( see [1] ) they state that some kind of post are not allowed for embedding, like communities post, or re-share of communities post. (see [3] )

Having a list of g+ activities id , i can fetch informations via the api, and have as a response an activity object ( see [2]).
But it seems that there is no way to see if the post is from a community or not,and therefore if the embedding will succeed or not.

do you know a way to avoid embedding white squares ?

Resource list:

[1] "How to" from g+ dev guide:  https://developers.google.com/+/web/embedded-post/

[2] Activity syntax : https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities?hl=it

[3] List of supported/unsupported posts: https://developers.google.com/+/web/embedded-post/#supported_posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posts to a community will have `access.description` be the name of the community while standard posts will have "Public". This is not a guaranteed standard so it could change at anytime.

[Example](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/plus/v1/plus.activities.get?activityId=z12kgbjjrurlybvp004cdvcajvuycvpx4gk&_h=1&)

```
"access": {
    "kind": "plus#acl",
    "description": "Web APIs (General)",
    "items": [
     {
      "type": "public"
     }
}
```